# Pressure volume curve; Is it wrong Ea?

Tags: heart, physiology

This is a continuation of the following question;
[Pressure volume curve; Is it wrong ESPVR?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32471/pressure-volume-curve-is-it-wrong-espvr)

In the pressure volume curve, if my understanding is correct, Ea is obtained by the following diagram (Refer to the Fig.1, below);

- 1st step; Draw a line of end-diastolic volume, as a vertical line drawn(sky-blue dot line in Fig.1) from point (A) or (B).
- 2nd step; The foot of the above-mentioned sky-blue dot line of the end-diastolic volume is named as point (H).
- 3rd step; Draw a straight line connecting the upper left corner (point (C))  of the pressure-volume curve and the point (H) just described , see the red line  in Fig.1,
- 4th step; The 'absolute value' of the slope of red line in Fig.1 thus drawn is equal to Ea.

[image] 
Fig,1 Definition of Ea's line; Here, the Japanese word 「後負荷」 in Figure 1 means afterload.

Given the assumption that the intraventricular pressure (henceforth Pes) at the upper left angle point approximates the mean blood pressure (Pm),

Ea = Pe/stroke volume ≒ Pm/stroke volume

So considering a manner of Ohm's law, the Ea means the "vascular resistance of the aorta."

However, I found the following figure, in the JOVE, an established journal;

[image]
Fig.2:Quoted from https://www.jove.com/t/54149/rodent-working-heart-model-for-study-myocardial-performance-oxygen?

My question;

> The absolute value of the slope of the green line in this figure seems to indicate Ea, is this correct?

Here, in the figure I quoted, it is not actually specified in the paper what SVR stands for, but SVR probably stands for "Systemic Vascular Resistance(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vascular_resistance)", not "Surgical ventricular restoration(https://www.ncvc.go.jp/english/hospital/section/cvs/hcs/svr/)" .